# Numbers in quadrants of a circle - help me solve it

Tags: pattern

I saw this puzzle and don't know how to solve it:

[image: puzzle self]

The only pattern I saw is 3 + 8 = 11 , 2 + 9 = 11, 6 + 2 = 8 and 1 + 7 = 8

Are there other approaches I should consider?

Comment: Try calculating the angle between the clock hands when time is 3hr 6 min, 2 hr 1 min, check different combinations, also make sure the puzzle is correct

Comment: @Francisco did you find the solution by now?

Comment: @Avigrail Not yet .. some different tip of attempts presented here? ty.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think is it but could be a start.. A bit like what you pointed out in the answer,

> The numbers in the fifth circle show the difference between the corresponding quarter of the top-right and bottom-left circles. I.e. 8 - 1 = 7, 9 - 3 = 6, 2 - 4 = (-)2

So maybe the question mark should be:

> 5   (which is 7-2)

because it fits this pattern, but that doesn't feel like a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

All I found was a diagonal reference. You build the two differences (always positive) and chose the smaller one.

[image]

So for top left this would be '8' and **'7'**,
top right '9' and **'6'**,
bottom left **'2'** and again **'2'** (is this a sign?)

and following this rules, bottom right would be '7' and **'5'**.

Comment: Hey that works, it's better than what I had because it uses all of the numbers in some way.

Comment: @ladyofcats yeah, but I still don't think this is the intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The answer comes from differences of numbers between the 2nd and 4th circle..
>
> 8-1=7
> 9-3=6
> 4-2=2
>
> and the answer is 7-2 = 5

Answer (score 0):

Οne pattern I see is the following:

```
[6+1]-[3+2]=2
[4+2]-[3+1]=4
[11+11]-[8+8]=6
[9+8]-[7+2]=8
[7+6]-[2+1]=10
```

From the addition and subtraction of these numbers we obtain the arithmetic progression: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. If we divide them by 2, then we can say they represent time on a clock: 1 pm, 2 pm, 3 pm, 4 pm, 5 pm.